# How to write lambda as def function?

Tags: python, function, dataframe, lambda

How do I write the below lambda function as a def function?

```
df['hourly'] = df['Salary Estimate'].apply(lambda x: 1 if 'per hour' in x.lower() else 0)
```

Comment: just do `def f(args): return <expression in lambda>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def fun(x):
   return 1 if 'per hour' in x.lower() else 0
```

then

```
df['hourly'] = df['Salary Estimate'].apply(fun)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def my_super_fun(x):
    return 1 if 'per hour' in x.lower() else 0
df['hourly'] = df['Salary Estimate'].apply(my_super_fun)
```

You can pass any one-argument function to `apply` function.